# How to track external url with google analytics

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have a page who redirect to an external url and I want to track the url.

sample :

MyPage.aspx (render like)

```
<a target="_blank" href="Redirect.aspx?id=123456">
<a target="_blank" href="Redirect.aspx?id=abcde">
```

Redirect.aspx.vb

```
 url = GetUrlById(id)

Response.Redirect(url)

or     

Response.Clear()
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader("Location", url) //could be google.com or any external link
Response.End()
```

How to track the url with google analytics?

Comment: Unsure I understood, but if you're redirecting an external site, you obviously can't track _their site_. So, you'll have to [track the `event`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) on the  link clicked _at your site_

Comment: like you see, the hyperlink just have an id. I will need to add the url as property or add ajax to get the url by id. I search an alternative to that.

Comment: You may find useful google analytics event tracking to [track outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) to POST a Custom Event to Google Analytics.

In your VB code, before either `Response.Redirect`ing or `Response.End`ing your redirect, you would have to make an HTTP Post Request to the Analytics Endpoint with the required data in order to log the Custom Event.

You can check the official documentation here for the list of available and required parameters: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events